# Virtual Windows - App Not Connecting to Internet

Tags: google-compute-engine

I installed a new app and now getting stuck signing into the app. I'm guessing it is not allowing internet access to the app. I don't know if I need to adjust the settings inside windows or inside my instance.

Currently I have https and http access enabled, and that's about it.

Internet Explorer works, so I'm not sure. Welcome any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the http and https firewall rules only allow the port 80 and the port 443 respectively, and it is possible that your application uses another port.

To check which port is being used by your application follow this steps:

1. Open the command prompt - **start » run » cmd or start » All Programs » Accessories » Command Prompt**.
2. Type `tasklist | findstr '[application_name]'`. Replace the `[application_name]` with the application that you want to check (for example, apache) and hit enter.
3. Make note of the PID (second column) from the details shown.
4. Type `netstat -aon | findstr '[PID]'`. Replace the `[PID]` from the above step and hit enter.
5. You’ll be shown the application detail and the corresponding port to which it is listening.

You can check the following [link](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/10/how-to-check-which-application-is-using-which-port/) where this process is well explained.

Once you have identified the port you are using, you can create a new rule for your instance

You can create the rule with the following command:

```
gcloud compute --project=my-project firewall-rules create rule-for-test --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:[PORT] --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0
```

The output should be something like:

```
Creating firewall...⠹Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project...l/firewalls/rule-for-test].
Creating firewall...done.
NAME              NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW     DENY  DISABLED
rule-for-test    default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:[PORT]        False
```

Please check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) for further information.

Also you need to open the port in  your windows firewall:

1. From the **Start** menu, click **Control Panel**, click **System and Security**, and then click **Windows Firewall**. Control Panel is not configured for 'Category' view, you only need to select **Windows Firewall**.
2. Click **Advanced Settings**.
3. Click **Inbound Rules**.
4. Click **New Rule** in the **Actions** window.
5. Click **Rule Type** of **Port**.
6. Click Next.
7. On the **Protocol and Ports** page click TCP.
8. Select **Specific Local Ports** and type a value something like 5000-5010 (this is only an example you need to add the ports needed)
9. Click Next.
10. On the Action page click **Allow the connection**.
11. Click Next.
12. On the **Profile** page click the appropriate options for your environment.
13. Click Next.
14. On the Name page enter a name of like “Open port for test”
15. Click Finish.
16. **Restart** the Instance.

I hope this information would be useful to you